# How can I make a saving code faster? -MatLab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm running a short code to open one by one a list of files and saving back only one of the variables contained in the files. The process seems to me much slower than I expected and getting slower with time, I don't fully understand why and how I could make it run faster. I always struggle with optimization. I'd appreciate if you have suggestions.

The code is the following (the ... substitute the actual path just for example):

```
main_dir=dir(strcat('\\storage2-...\Raw\DAQ5\'));

filename={};
for m=7:size(main_dir,1)
    m
    second_dir=dir([main_dir(m).folder '\' main_dir(m).name '\*.mat']);
    for mm=1:numel(second_dir)
        filename{end+1}=[second_dir(mm).folder '\' second_dir(mm).name];
        for mmm=1:numel(filename)
            namefile=sprintf(second_dir(mm,1).name);
            load(string(filename(1,mmm)));
            save(['\\storage2-...\DAQ5\Ch1_',namefile(end-18:end-4),'.mat'], 'Ch_1_y')
        end
    end
end
```

The original file is about 17 MB and once the single variable is saved it is about 6 MB in size.

Comment: For every dir you add to `filename`, but then in the inner most loop (`mmm`) you start looping through all filenames, not just the most recent. So first time you read all files in dir1, second time you read files in dir1 & dir 2, third time all files in dir1 & dir2 & dir3 and so on, so all the files in dir1 will be loaded and saved repeatedly.
There are some other issues (unneeded `strcat` and `sprintf`), but this is the logical issue I think.

Comment: To finish Justin's train of thought, you can move the `mmm` loop to the end of your code, outside of the other loops, or you can get rid of the `mmm` loop entirely and just operate on the current (`mm`) file name.  You could probably further reduce your looping by using a recursive directory search for `dir( '\\storage-2\...\Raw\DAQ5\**\*.mat' )` to find all nested mat files with a single `dir` call (this is MATLAB version dependent, but has been around for several years)

Comment: Run your code in the Matlab Profiler to determine where it's actually spending its time, and where you should focus your improvement efforts! https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matlab `load` function takes an optional additional argument to specify just a selected variable to read from the input file.

```
s = load('path/to/file.mat', 'Ch_1_y');
```

That way you don't have to spend time loading in all the other variables from those input `.mat` files that you're just going to immediately throw away.

And using `save` to save MAT-files over SMB shares can be slow. You might want to call `save` to write it to a temporary local file first, and then copy the completed file to the final destination. Sounds like more I/O, but it can actually be a net win, depending on your particular system and network. Measure it both ways to see if it's a win in your particular situation.